# Who actually was Major Berenson at Hinzerhaus, in Gaunt's Ghost?

Tags: warhammer-40k, gaunts-ghosts

In *Gaunt's Ghosts, The Lost, second part, Only In Death*, the Ghosts are joined by Major Berenson, from the 52 Cadogus and another guy.

At the end of the story, we learn the following (translated from French to English by me, may not be the original text):

> ... Major Berenson has been killed in action. 
> ... 
> I tried to get him out of the flames, but it was too late. 
> Backer looked at him with a puzzled look.
> - Have I said something wrong, colonel ? asked Hark.
> - The valkyrie which flew major Berenson to Hinzerhaus has been shot down five days ago.
>  Obviously, Major Berenson was killed before he could join the Tanith.

Here is the text from page 255 of the English language version:

> “Are you all right, commissar?” Bacler asked, frowning at him.
> “Yes. I just remembered. It is with regret I have to inform you that your Major Berenson was killed in the line of duty.”
> “Yes, that was a bloody shame,” Bacler replied. Hark nodded towards the blackened shell of the Valkyrie on the slope behind them. “I wanted to pull him clear, but it was too late,” he said.
> Bacler looked at him oddly. “Did I say something wrong, colonel?” Hark asked.
> “Major Berenson was lost when his Valkyrie was brought down en route to Hinzerhaus five days ago,” said Bacler.

Who (what) was Major Berenson?

Does it have a link with the Sanctioned Psyker transported by the Cadogus regiment?

Comment: Maybe he was a g-g-g-ghost! Or possibly the theme park owner in disguise...

Comment: He is mentioned to look similar to Caffran, who had died in a previous novel. It is likely it was the psyker who created him

Comment: I do think think there is a canon answer to this question.  It is a ghost story.

Comment: I translated the term "assermented psyker" from French into English as "Sanctioned Psyker".  Please correct this as needed - my French is quite thin.

Comment: Google trad gives me "sworn". But that actually has no real impact on the question. @DoscoJones

Comment: @Valorum Merrt ? is that you ?

Comment: ["Sanctioned Psyker"](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Sanctioned_Psyker)  is a term from the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's implied, but not outright stated, that Berenson is a projection of the sanctioned psyker.**

Many of the other ghostly apparitions - such as Bragg, Cuu, Dorden's son, and the dame in the black dress - are more directly confirmed to be the work of the psyker, as evidenced by

> the scene after Hark kills Soric, where each of these apparitions "passes on" one by one.

The dame is another hint that the psyker is the one responsible: whereas most of the apparitions come from people the Ghosts know, the dame is one of the psyker's handlers. Because neither the psyker nor the Ghosts actually knew Berenson, his appearance is filled in by someone they did know, Caffran.

Throughout the book, the psyker tries to support the Ghosts with his apparitions - giving them warning of incoming attacks, leading Baskevyl to the fortress's power supply. Berenson supplying information about the progress of the battle fits into the same pattern.

> It's also a neat thematic tie to when Soric's power first manifested in *Straight Silver*. There, his precognition took the form of a message shell that would be used by a courier in battle. Here, it's progressed to a whole courier.